# How to make parallel async and await use 100% of the cpu?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I have searched a lot of codes saying that is possible to use multiple cores with parallel async, but none worked. It is always stuck in a single core.

Is it possible?

**This is uses 100% of the cpu:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 100000, p =>
        {
            while (true) { }
        });
    }
}
```

**Using parallel async, I dont get more than 12%:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(i =>
            {
                while (true) { }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

**100% cpu. Thanks all that helped, and not just mocked or tried to close:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (true) { }
                }));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why -3? What is wrong?

Comment: @Servy: Not sure whether this is a duplicate. The other post has to do with output to Console.

Comment: I asked to closed the other, due to me being unable to make a proper question. I formulated this question in details to get a good answer and go and screw me over. Nice. Good job

Comment: Your code is flawed, Parallel.For will create n threads partitioning the execution, Task.Run will create only one task, one thread, if you want to use more then you must create multiple tasks, one per thread supported by the processor.

Comment: Thanks! got it right

Comment: instead of using `100` use `for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)` then it will just make the same number of threads as you have cores.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Because it sounds like you're trying to circumvent performance bottlenecks, when you should be improving code elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only creates one task, Task.FromResult returns a finished task and it's added after the while loop, that will be executed 100000 times, but one after other as the generation is done by the synchronous function Select.

You can change your code to this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(i =>
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true) { }

                return 0;
            });
        });


        Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }
}
```

It will use the 100%, tested.

Answer (score -1):

When `WhenAll` goes to get the first task, it'll ask your query, `task`, for the first task.  It will use the selector to try to translate the first result of `Range` (`0`), into a `Task`.  Since your selector has an infinite loop, that will never return.  The only work that ever happens is sitting waiting for the first task to be generated, when it never will be.

Other than that your main thread does nothing but ask a thread pool thread to do all the things, you never create any additional threads, and thus have no oppertunity to use multiple cores on your CPU.

Comment: Could you, please, show an example how to make this code run 100% of the cpu?

Comment: @FernandoSilva Start by creating an asynchronous CPU bound operation.  When you've figured out how to create a single operation that runs asynchronously and uses the CPU *then* you can work on how to call it multiple times.

Comment: If you could, please, elaborate with an example. This is not helping. Is too vague.

Comment: I have read all the links I could find for parallel async and tried the examples. None got near 100% cpu

Comment: @FernandoSilva `Task.Run` is specifically designed to asynchronously execute a CPU bound operation.